# How align header in top, footer in bottom of the page and main between them in bootstrap 5.3

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Iam new to bootstrap.  I used bootstrap 5.3 in this html page.  Now i want to align header in the top, footer in the bottom and size of the main between them.  I tried the following html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test Webpage</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js""></script>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body style="min-height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(100,100,100);">
    <header style="background-color: rgb(210, 210, 241);">
    Header
    </header>
    <main  style="background-color: rgb(185, 185, 215);">
    Main content
    </main>
    <footer style="background-color: rgb(235, 235, 255);">
    Footer
    </footer>
    </body>
</head>
```

The following out is generated from above code

[image]

I want output like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML consists of 3 parts:

- header (use [Bootstrap's navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/))
- content
- footer

The key is to use Bootstrap's `flex-grow-1` class on the content and `flex-shrink-0` on the footer to push the footer all the way down to the bottom of the page. Also, add Bootstrap's classes `d-flex` and `flex-column` to the `<body>`.

See the snippet below.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
  <!-- Header -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <div id="page-content" class="flex-grow-1">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1 class="fw-light mt-4 text-white">Sticky Footer using Flexbox</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white-50">Use just two Bootstrap utility classes and three custom CSS rules and you will have a flexbox enabled sticky footer for your website!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="flex-shrink-0 py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works fine.  That I expected